# Regex to match string endswith wildcard character

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that can match the long string divide by semicolon, with different pattern and they are endswith wildcard character `*`. For example:

```
abc-cd;efg-md*;abc:cde:fgh-ui*;jkl-{i*;uyz-12*
```

I wrote this regex

```
(^|;)(([aA0-zZ9]+)|(\W+))-([aA0-zZ9]+\*)
```

but it only match `;efg-md*;abc:cde:fgh-ui*;uyz-12*`. It does not match `;jkl-{i*`.

Can anyone have suggestion for the regex that works

Comment: `[aA0-zZ9]` is not how you match all letters and numbers. It should be `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it only match `;efg-md*;abc:cde:fgh-ui*;uyz-12*`. It does not match `;jkl-{i*`.

Because `;jkl-{i*` has the special character `{`. You need to accept `{` in your regex.

Also, I have a suggested solution. You could try following regex.

```
[^;]+\*(?=$|;)
```

**Details**:

- `[^;]+`: matches string which has not `;`
- `\*(?=$|;)`: matches character `*` if the next character of `*` is `;` or `end of line.`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tdVWvJ/1)

Comment: Thanks Than, it worked, but unfortunately, the regex I am using doesn't support positive lookahead, is there anyway I can substitute positive lookahead?

Comment: What is your regex you are using?

Comment: It is kusto regex, which use re2 library https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: I think you could work around using capturing group `([^;]+\*)($|;)`. After using `extract_all`, you could choose string which you want.
https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractallfunction#extract-a-subset-of-capture-groups

Answer (score 0):

The character class `[aA0-zZ9]+` matches one of `a`, `A`, a range from `0-z`, `Z` or `9`.

The range 0-z matches 48-122 in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and includes all the other chars listed in the character class so it is unnecessary to add them.

But as you can see in the ASCII table, it does not match chars like `*` `{` and `-`

However I suspect that you meant to use `[a-z0-9]+` and leave out A-Z as there are no uppercase chars in the example string.

Using `\W` does match all non word characters, but in the pattern that you tried it should be followed by `-` which will not match in the example data.

---

To match the string ending on an `*` you could extend the character class:

```
^[-0-9a-z+[*;:{]+\*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[-0-9a-z+[*;:{]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed characters
- `\*` Match `*`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UCKsS0/1)

Answer (score 0):

If your regex flavor doesn't support look around assertions, you can alter the regex as below.
It searches for non-semicolon character sequence ending with `*`.

```py
[^;]*?\*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UCKsS0/2)